# Move WSS 3.0 Database to SQL 2008

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I'm having a bit of an issue... I know next to nothing about sharepoint and I have to migrate a content database!

The problem : at some point someone has installed WSS 3.0 on our web server, the content database for this is on the local (WEB) server. I need to get the database moved onto a proper SQL Server so that it can be included in the normal nightly backup process (at the moment the database is not being backed up)

I have spent some time online looking into what needs to be done but as I dont have any WSS knowledge its a bit difficult!

Is any one able to offer any hints/tips/guides written for someone with little WSS/SharePoint knowledge?

Thanks in advance... Im off to try to do this on (and probably break) the test server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference I discovered that the way that our system has been set up is wrong, to rectify this we :

- Backed up all of the databases.
- Removed WSS from the server.
- Reinstalled WSS on the server using the advanced config to specify a SQL server rather than using a local embedded server.
- Finally se uses stsadm -o addcontentdatabase to re-attach the content databases to the new instance of WSS.